# Compile Error: Invalid Error Procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2013 and I put the following code into Sheet5 Code box and i try to compile it and get a Compile Error: Invalid Error Procedure

```
Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("C3").Value = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("G3")
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your sheets are spelled properly ? One is named "Sheet5" and the other "Sheets1". Notice that one has an extra "s". Also I'd say that you should be consistent. If you use an explicit call to the "Value" property then do it on both sides. Note that you can omit it on both sides.

Comment: I did change it to `Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("C3") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G3")` but the same compile error. I did rename the sheets from the original Sheet1 to Information Sheet and Sheet5 to Talley Sheet so i played with the code that way but the same error still occures

Comment: Then I supposed that you have not put the code in a function or in a sub. Can you post the entire code ?

Comment: I think you're right. In fact I was giving that answer as you were posting the comment. The error message in the title is close to what it would be for that error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you pasted the line of code into the worksheet module by itself and that the compile error you get is actually "Invalid Outside Procedure." If so, you need to put the code into a function or subroutine, something like:

```
Sub Test

Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("C3").Value = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("G3")

End Sub
```

Then you'll get a "Subscript Out of Range" error because you don't have sheets with those names, which will be progress :).